# How can I exclude a method inside a class with doxygen

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I am using Objective-C language. And I have 3 classes: Chicken, Dove, Dog. Each of class has run method.

```
Chicken.h
 -(void)run;

Dove.h
 -(void)run;

Dog.h
 -(void)run;
```

I want to exclude run method inside Dove class. I found that EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS can do that. But if I set configuration : EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = save, all save methods in 3 classes are excluded.

Am I able to exclude save method of Dove class only?

Comment: Not sure about giving a full qualified name like Dove::run. Another possibility would probably be to use the \cond \endcond construct.

Comment: Thank Albert. I tried Dove::run, but it doesn't work. I think \cond \endcond is a good choice in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know objective-c, but for C++ the only way I know to do this would be to pre-process it out. To do this set the configuration values:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
PREDEFINED             = DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
```

Then wrap the method you want excluded inside an ifndef block. Here is a C++ example:

```
/// doc comment for class Dove
class Dove {
public:
    /// doc comment for foo
    void foo();

#ifndef DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
    // the bar method will not be seen by doxygen, so you should not
    // see it in any documentation
    void bar();
#endif
};
```

This is a general strategy you may use. Anything inside the `#ifndef` blocks will be pre-processed away and will not be visible to doxygen.

Comment: Thank Phil. If we use pre-processing, the instance methods table is still appear save method. It is only disappear in method document table. :/

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by it is only disappear in method document table. I tried updating my answer to include a c++ example that is more complete. I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh cool! I am stupid. I added `#endif` in front of `void bar();` Thank @Phil